# How to compile vlc codebase(modules) with my local code changes?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vlc-media-player, ubuntu-20.04, dvb-t

I've tried to modify the below file from vlc codebase, but its not affecting on the final executable binary.(I didnt see my newly introduced prints & changes if i invoke the vlc binary. But this file is compiling properly.)

```
    **vlc/modules/codec/telx.c**
```

Could you please guide me the steps ?  should i copy the corresponding library into somewhere & build the vlc elf again ?

Steps followed to compile:

1. export PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/home/xxx/Projects/vlc_git_src/vlc/contrib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/pkgconfig
2. export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64
3. ./bootstrap
4. ./configure
5. make
6. ./vlc

After modifying my local change i will do only make & execute the elf.

Comment: Please explain any and all steps you did to create your "final executable binary" after modifying the source code file.

Comment: @Daniel B Steps followed to compile:

# export PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/home/anburaj/Projects/vlc_git_src/vlc/contrib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/pkgconfig
# export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64
# ./bootstrap
#./configure
# make
# ./vlc

After modifying my local change i will do only make & execute the elf.

Comment: Please add this information to your question. // When recompiling after changes, did you confirm that _make_ does pick up the changes and recompiles the code and everything dependent on it?

Comment: Thanks. Updated.

Yes, if i put #err on that file then compilation got stopped.
So, i can say that my changes are there.

Comment: I can see my symbol(anburaj) here,

# nm modules/.libs/libtelx_plugin.so
0000000000003360 t anburaj
                 U __assert_fail@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U block_Release

Comment: Sounds great. You could use `strace` to see if VLC is indeed loading the plugin library from that file or perhaps from elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you. Found the solution. We should mention/pass the corresponding module name while executing the vlc elf.  ***  # ./vlc --codec avcodec,telx  ***   with this now its referring my compiled .so file and could see my changes at runtime..

Reference: 
https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:VLC_Modules_Loading/

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution. Make sure to add it as an answer below! You can then accept your own answer after 24 hours or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to pass the module details while executing vlc elf like below,

```
 ./vlc --codec avcodec,telx
```

By default VLC will refer the caching module info while running. If you want to include your latest modified module/code then follow the above options. It works.